# getting input data with event "onkeyup"

Tags: java, wicket

I have small problem with getting input data while event "onkeyup" is triggered on it. I have such inputs and other datas:

```
// El-cheapo model for form
private static final ValueMap cheapModel = new ValueMap();
//some code...
//...

Form form = new Form( "pushNotificationForm" );
form.setOutputMarkupId( true );

final Label actualSizeLabel = new Label( ACTUAL_NOTIFICATION_SIZE_ID, new Model<String>( actualSize ) );
actualSizeLabel.setOutputMarkupId( true );

final TextField<String> titleTextField = new TextField<String>( TITLE_TEXTFIELD_ID, new PropertyModel<String>(
            cheapModel, TITLE_TEXTFIELD_ID ) );
    titleTextField.setRequired( true );
    titleTextField.add( new AjaxEventBehavior( "onkeyup" )
    {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent( AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget )
        {
            actualSize = Integer.toString( (getTitle() ).getBytes().length );
            ajaxRequestTarget.add( actualSizeLabel );
        }
    } );
form.add( titleTextField );
form.add( actualSizeLabel );
//.. some code
//later
private String getTitle()
{
    return cheapModel.getString( TITLE_TEXTFIELD_ID );
}
```

The actualSize remains null, untill I submit the form, but why? Any help please

Comment: Because you do not submit the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.html). However, since your behaviour is attached to the onkeyup event, you may also want to use [throttling](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html#setThrottleDelay%28org.apache.wicket.util.time.Duration%29).

Comment: That was the solution :) Do you have any idea how overcome problem when TextField is required and when I type something into field, then delete, I get "required field" error msg for feedback panel?

Comment: The easiest solution is to move your validation into a form-level validator. Those are only run when the full form is submitted, but not when a single field is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Its because form processing (and subsequently the writing of the values into the model) will be done only when you submit it, not at any ajax callback from some of your components.

I think, you can try to get the raw value from the text field:

```
String currentValue = titleTextField.getRawInput();
```